# http://stackexchange.com/ onebox is white

Tags: bug, chat, onebox

I just oneboxed `http://stackexchange.com/`, but the image was pure white (I think): https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1984006#1984006. Thinking that this may have been a MSE-only issue, I did it in two other rooms [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/15912685#15912685) and [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/15017478#15017478). Both times, it was was the same white image.

> [image]

This can be fixed by changing `<img src="http://cdn-chat.sstatic.net/chat/img/se-logo-white.png"` to `<img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackexchange/img/logo.png`.